# Formatting a possibly nil value as hours and minutes

Tags: ruby, datetime, formatting, null

This might be a bit silly because there are like a thousand ways to do this, but I'm struggling to come up with one that I like. I feel like this should fit in one line, but I don't like re-using read_attribute(:length) lots and I don't like the below because it's not that clear.

```
# returns a human-readable string in the format Xh Ym
def length
  # length stored in seconds
  len = read_attribute(:length)
  "#{(len/60/60).floor}h #{len.modulo(60*60)/60}m" unless len.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one line

```
def length
  (len = read_attribute(:length)) && "#{(len/60/60).floor}h #{len.modulo(60*60)/60}m"
end
```

If `len == nil` return `nil`, if not - second operand

Answer (score 4):

One-liners are nice, but sometimes it's better just to split lines. For example:

```
def length
  if (len = read_attribute(:length))
    "#{(len/60/60).floor}h #{len.modulo(60*60)/60}m" 
  end
end
```

If you really like compact code that deals with nil values, you can work with the idea of `maybe`'s [ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/):

```
def length
  read_attribute(:length).maybe { |len| "#{(len/60/60).floor}h #{len.modulo(60*60)/60}m" }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that len is an integer you won't need to use floor. You can do something like this

```
"#{len/3600}h #{(len/60) % 60}m" unless len.nil?
```